# How do I access the filename of the CSV file I just opened?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a method that looks like this:

```
def extract_websites
  websites = []
  csvs = Dir["#{@dir_name}/#{@state}/*.csv"]

  csvs.each do |csv|
    CSV.foreach(csv, headers: true) do |row|
      websites << row['Website']
    end
  end
  websites.uniq!
end
```

But what I need want to do is for each CSV file that is opened, I would like to detect the name of that file.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample the variable `csv` holds the path of the CSV file.
That local variable is available in the blocks of its children, it shares its scope down but not upwards.

So:

```
def extract_websites
  websites = []
  csvs = Dir["#{@dir_name}/#{@state}/*.csv"]

  csvs.each do |csv|
    puts File.expand_path(csv) # show the full path for each csv file
    CSV.foreach(csv, headers: true) do |row|
      puts csv # shows unexpanded path for each row of a csv
      websites << row['Website']
    end
  end
  websites.uniq!
end
```

should print out the path for each CSV file and for each `row`.